# Is it kosher to eat live fish

Tags: kashrut-kosher, fish

In some countries people like to eat animals that are still alive (e.g. dancing squid / octopus).
Clearly these animals are not kosher, but it is also possible to eat kosher-types fish that are either still alive, or that may appear to be alive (e.g. still moving).

1) The Noahide laws (when translated to English) prohibit eating flesh taken from an *animal* while it is still alive. But, are fish considered to be animals in this case?
2) According to my research, the act of removing fish from water qualifies as slaughtering them. But, removing fish from water doesn't actually kill it.

So, is it kosher to eat a live fish? There's a mention that it is kosher here: [Why do Fish not need Shechita?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16092/why-do-fish-not-need-shechita) , but there's limited discussion on the matter.

edit- to restate my question: Is it kosher to eat a live fish?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for bringing your question here. I hope you stick around and enjoy. But note that the site doesn't guarantee validity or offer rabbinic advice: treat info here like it came from some friends. ¶ Can I ask you to [clarify](http://yodeya.com/posts/36613/edit)? Namely: You mention Noahide laws, but are you asking about them? That is, is your question about the 'kosher' laws as they apply to Jews or to non-Jews? ¶ Finally, I suggest you [register](http://yodeya.com/users/login) your account for [access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more site features.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason I mention Noahide laws is because they supersede kashrut. If fish are considered as animals under Noahide, then clearly a jew cannot eat them while still living.

Comment: I have no particular to reason to think that's correct. I do know that there are things that are forbidden to Noahides under their laws that are permitted to Jews under theirs (ours); I believe the classic case is that of a properly (according to Jewish law) slaughtered animal that has not yet ceased its death throes. That may possibly be applicable here (to fish), too, though I don't know. Perhaps you should [edit] in to the question whether you're actually asking about Noahide or Jewish law (or both) so you get the answers you seek. Cf. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66378.

Comment: Does the fish have fins and scales?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Rama on Yoreh De'ah 13:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9145&st=&pgnum=40&hilite=) says that it is forbidden to eat a fish while it's alive due to it being disgusting. (Baal Teshakzu)

[Mishna Torah Hilchos Shechita 1:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5301.htm#4) says it is permitted to eat live fish.

Comment: Is that really an objective rule?

Comment: I believe there's a place more explicit that excludes fish from the Isur.

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5301.htm#4

Comment: maybe the rambam means "raw" not "live". I have seen the word "ochel chayim" refer to eating raw meat in the talmud.

Comment: @ray, good point, but see [here](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%91%D7%9C_%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%9B%D7%96) for a longer discussion. The Meiri and the Maggid Mishna both say he means alive.

Comment: See the Simla Chadasha which holds that if one washed it very well that it is not disgusting one can eat it

Answer (score 4):

According to [Chullin 101b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=101b&format=pdf), Ever Min Hachai does not apply to fish and locusts and thus something like this might be permissible. However, nonetheless it might be considered Tza'ar Ba'alei Chaim (Unnecessary pain to animals) and forbidden.

Comment: Does Tza'ar Ba'alei Chaim apply to fish as well? I remember learning that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Rabeinu Yona in shaarei teshuva part 3 #93 says it is Biblically forbidden from the verse "You shall not make your souls abominable..." (Lev.11:43)

"we are warned from this verse to not eat things disgusting to the soul, to not eat a fish or chagav until it is dead..."

Answer (score 0):

I agree with gershon  in regards that its disgusting according to the Rama. However I would assume that  since fish don't have the prohibition of "you shalt not consume blood", and fish don't require kosher slaughter. So with those two concepts together it appears to me that fish aren't animals according to Torah law (with the exception to trapping and killing them on the sabbath.) and therefore regarding violating the noahide laws it's not a problem. However it is forbidden because it's disgusting

Answer (score -3):

One should not eat live fish due to maras ayin, if not for any other reason.  Onlooker might after watching it think it is okay to commit ever min ha chai.

Comment: Do you have any source for that idea? There are many things that we do that can be misconstrued but unless there is a rabbinical source forbidding it we do not assume something is prohibited because of maaris ayin

Comment: Presumably there will be scales on the fish still if it's still alive, so no maras ayin.