# Is cooking food in one's mouth forbidden on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, cooking-bishul, shabbat

If someone put an uncooked food into his mouth on shabbos, and then drinks water which is hot enough to cook the food (עירוי כלי ראשון שיד סולדת בו or if the food was מקלי הבישול even from a כלי שני) is this considered cooking? Is he עובר on בישול בשבת?

If not, why not?

Comment: I don't think so. My understanding is this is the reason as to why I've seen people put the sugar cube in their mouth and drink tea with the cube in their mouth rather than putting the cube directly into the tea.

Comment: Sounds painful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure as far as halacha is concerned this is classified as "eating" and "drinking"

Comment: For a start this is a massive shinui, so at worst it will be drabanan

Comment: @Josh K But nonetheless, why should it not be considered a דבר שאינו מתכוין with פסיק רישא?

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Why shinui? Why not  דבר שאינו מתכוין with פסיק רישא?

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore because that's not how you cook...

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Same with dragging a bed or a bench over soft ground, which is considered דבר שאינו מתכוין with פסיק רישא for choresh, even though that's not how you plow.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore it's true that not all plowing and toldos of plowing involve dragging heavy objects, but no cooking involves putting the boiling water in your mouth. I may be wrong with my reasoning though.

Comment: @DoubleAA <sounds painful> Not so painful, if you other consider situations where we are concerned about bishul, eg. putting uncooked sugar in hot  tea, putting bread etc. into hot soup, and yet we drink/reat the hot tea/soup while its still very hot.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons Its not a different way of cooking. One of  the usual ways of cooking is putting uncooked food together with hot water. If someone mixed uncooked food with hot water in a wheelbarrow, would that be called a shinui? The unusual utensil which it is cooked in doesnt make it a Shnui.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore, check out the answer to "regurgitating forbidden species" https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92012/regurgitating-living-forbidden-species, halachically speaking, once you put food in your mouth, you ate it. We are also unconcerned about your digestive system "cooking" raw food on shabbat even though we refrain from making ceviche

Comment: @JoshK "we refrain from making ceviche" Huh? I thought ceviche is raw

Comment: It's raw fish chemically "cooked" by the acidity of the lime juice it's soaked in, @DanF, that must be some kind of mealacha, right?

Comment: @JoshK I don't think that is a melacha at all, but you may want to ask a question about that. There is a prohibition against pickling, and the marinating as happens to make ceviche may fall into that category, which is a different melacha from *bishul* - cooking.

Comment: @JoshK I've asked https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92385/5275

Comment: VERY good idea,  @DanF

Comment: @JoshK Felize Shabbat y Buenas Shavuout

Comment: De igual modo, @DanF, un Shabat muy feliz y un muy buen Shavuot