# May one marinate fish on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, cooking-bishul, fish

I was viewing O.C. 321 and there are a few halachot at the beginning that mentions that one cannot salt or put cabbage in vinegar on Shabbat because it is similar to cooking. My understanding of this rule is that it seems to be in terms of preserving the vegetable for later. There seem to be permission to salt vegetables that will be eaten immediately.

Ceviche is a dish made by marinating raw fish in lemon or lime juice, mainly. If the ceviche will be eaten for a Shabbat meal, may one marinate the fish? Are the parameters of the marinating prohibition based on either the type of food being marinated (i.e. are veggies a problem but fish is not?) or is it a "time" concern (i.e., it's not a problem if you are eating the food immediately.)

Comment: Logistically speaking, Peruvians will only make ceviche with freshly purchased fish and freshly squeezed limes, so an "authentic" ceviche on Shabbat is out of the question

Comment: @JoshK Obviously, you can't catch the fish on Shabbat. But, for Yom Tov, you can, and enjoy squeezing the limes as well.

Comment: I wonder if squeezing the limes directly onto the fish would be OK though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Mishna Berura in 321:5 (21) states that one may **not** salt **raw** fish or meat; whether to eat it on that Shabbat or to prevent it from spoiling.

He says that it's a **Rabbinic** decree as it looks like one is preserving it, since the salt makes it edible.

> {כא} אסור למלוח וכו' - דהא דמתירין לעיל בביצה למלחה היינו לצורך אותה סעודה אבל למלוח הבשר וביצה כדי להניח לאחר זמן דמי לעיבוד וכבישה והנה דעת המ"א וט"ז דאפילו דעתו לאכול ביומו אם הוא לצורך סעודה אחרת יש ליזהר בזה [והיינו כשהסעודה אחרת נמשך זמן רב אחר סעודה ראשונה] אבל הא"ר מצדד דאין לאסור רק אם בדעתו להניח לאחר שבת וכן משמע מביאור הגר"א ובפרט אם העת חם והוא 
>   עושה כן כדי שלא יסריח בודאי יש להקל לצורך סעודה אחרת דגם הט"ז מתיר בזה
>    **- בשר או דג חי אסור למולחו בשבת כדי שלא יסריח ואפילו במקום הפסד אסור ואפילו רוצה למלחו כדי לאכלו אחר מליחתו חי אסור דאע"ג דאין עיבוד באוכלין מדאורייתא מ"מ אסור דמתחזי כעיבוד שהמלח מכשיר האוכל ומתקנו** אבל מותר להדיח הבשר כדי לאכלו אח"כ חי ואין זה מקרי תיקון שאין התיקון בגוף הבשר אלא שמדיחו משום דם בעין שעליו. ומ"מ נראה דאסור להדיח הבשר שלא נמלח כשחל יום ג' להיות בשבת וכדי שלא יאסר אח"כ לבישול כיון שאין רוצה לאכול היום וגם אין דרך לאכול חי ניכר שעושה לצורך חול ואפילו ע"י א"י אסור להדיח שאין כאן הפסד כ"כ אם לא ידיחנו שיוכל לאכול צלי כ"כ המג"א ומיירי ביחיד בביתו אבל בקצב המוכר לאחרים בודאי יש הפסד בזה ויכול לעשות ע"י א"י וכן באווזות פטומות שיפסיד השומן אם יצלם גם להמ"א מותר ע"י א"י אפי' יחיד בביתו. ואפי' בבשר בהמה הסכימו הרבה אחרונים דיש להקל להדיח ע"י א"י ודלא כמ"א ועיין בא"ר ובתשובת נודע ביהודה שכתבו דאם אי אפשר ע"י א"י מותר גם ע"י ישראל אך אם מונח הבשר בכלי טוב שירחוץ ידיו עליו עד שיהיה שרוי הבשר במים:‏

Comment: I'm not sure this is answering my question. It mentions specifically salting and the last bolded word מתקנו implies preserving. Then immediately after that it says that you can soak it.  Making ceviche doesn't really involve preserving it in salt to preserve it. You marinate it in juice to steep the taste into it and, it might be bishul, but it's unclear

Comment: @DanF: מתקנו means _fix it_ - i.e. make it edible, not preserve it. (As well as מכשיר  which means _makes it ready_ - kind of saying the same thing twice.) להדיח  means _to rinse_.