# Can a Ben-Noach eat live oysters?

Tags: halacha, noachide-laws

I understand that animals shouldn't be eaten until after death occured. Although an oyster is a shell fish and not kosher, could a Ben Noach eat live oysters?

I understand it is the custom of non jews to eat some fish and sea food raw. This second sentence may be another question entirely, or it duplicates another answer if it has been answered that eating any living thing, including seafood and fish that has not been killed is not allowed for Ben Noach's. For example: a question about shushi. I didn't find an answer for raw fish or shell fish.

Comment: related: [Is it kosher to eat live fish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36613/11501)

Comment: Yes it's permitted. Deducted from SA YD 13.1.   https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%92_%D7%90

Answer (score 1):

Rambam [Hilchot Melachim 9:11](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188354/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-9.htm#v11) writes that non-Jews are forbidden from eating limbs or flesh from a live domesticated or wild land animal. However, he believes that poultry are not included in this prohibition.

He doesn’t mention fish or other seafood, but the clear implication is that there is no prohibition there either.

Comment: Just wondering, where did the Rambam permit poultry?

Comment: In melachim 9:11... link is in the answer

Comment: Ah yes didn't realize, he says a ben Noach isn't killed for it but does that mean it's completely permitted?

Comment: Like in the previous halacha regarding blood, he uses the word "mutar" as opposed to the next one

Comment: Interesting question. Is there anything that is forbidden for a Ben Noach but that he is not killed for?

Comment: If shellfish have the same din as  other fish, they would be considered "slaughtered" from the moment they are removed from the ocean. In that case, it would be no issue for a Ben Noach.

Answer (score 0):

The Rambam in Hil. Shechitah 1:3 says that one is allowed to eat fish and grasshoppers while they are alive. The acharonim say that the same rule applies to bnei Noach.

Comment: Although I think he says it's prohibited since it's disgusting. I guess that doesn't apply to a ben noach

Comment: @robev I don’t think Rambam says that, although others do