# What are God's requirements please that allow us to eat an animal

Tags: torah-study

Can anyone explain what God requires for us to be able to eat meat? Which animals are ok to eat please? Are there any parts of animals we are not allowed to eat? Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kashrut is a good start

Comment: I am downvoting this question, which I almost never do. I thought at first it was a bit basic, but based on the OP’s own comments on the answer, it was not asked in good faith. They knew what would be answered, and used the question as a setup for a debate. BTW the answer was an excellent overview.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149692/discussion-on-question-by-2malachi-com-what-are-gods-requirements-please-that-a); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Many teachers ask open questions (in good faith) to elicit responses.

Answer (score 6):

**0) Who are the laws for?**

Judaism understands that the below laws apply only to members of the Jewish nation. Non-Jews are not bound by any of the laws, except that they must at ensure the animal is dead before they eat any part of it. See (2) below whether this prohibition includes fish.

**1) Which animal?**

As per Leviticus 11, land animals must both chew the cud and have split hooves (so cows, sheep, goats, deer are OK. Pigs, horses and camels are not).

Fish must have fins and scales (so tuna and salmon are fine, shark and sturgeon are not).

Birds are a little complicated, but basically birds of prey are not OK, others are fine. The categories get blurred, but chicken, turkey and pigeons are fine.

Insects and shellfish are prohibited, except for some species of locust.

**2) Method of Slaughter**

Land animals require a special ritual slaughter before eating - if this is not done correctly the animal may not be eaten https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shechita, as do birds (though the process is easier, I believe). Fish and locusts can be killed in any way (and possibly do not need killing at all [Is it kosher to eat live fish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36613/is-it-kosher-to-eat-live-fish))

The animal must not have received certain injuries before it is slaughtered - mainly ones that are understood to lead to it dying of the wound (eg a punctured lung)

**3) Which parts?**

Animal and bird blood may not be eaten, and is removed from the meat through a special process https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shechita#Kashering

Certain fats must be removed from animals,  mainly in the hindquarters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikkur. In practice many (though not all) authorities view the process as too complicated to do correctly on an industrial scale, and the hindquarters are not eaten (and are sold to non-Jews)

**4) Meat and milk**

Meat (including from birds, but not fish) may not be eaten in the same meal or cooked together with dairy products. After eating meat the custom is to wait 1 - 6 hours before eating dairy (but not the other way round).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149693/discussion-on-answer-by-aka-what-are-gods-requirements-please-that-allow-us-to); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.